# How to change environment in R plumber?

Tags: r, api, plumber

I am facing a problem using plumber, when I "plumb" my code all my data.tables are reset to data.frame after each set of operations.

I thought the issue could be due to environment.I tried to play with envir parameter in the plumb function but nothing seems to work.

I have tried both versions of plumber (CRAN repo and Github). Any help/ directions would be highle appreciated, thanks in advance!

P.S. The code works fine w/o plumber.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Jeff, I solved the problem myself. The issue was due to a probable bug in the package (data.table), in some cases after using mutate() a data.table is reverted back to a data.frame. I had a similar issue in the previous year so I loaded (dtplyr) along with (data.table) and everything works smooth.

Although not necessary at the moment but do you know how can we change the environment in plumber() to "GlobalEnv" ?